# Бинарный поиск c доп условием

Tags: c++, алгоритм

***Бинарный поиск***

Дан массив из nn элементов, упорядоченный в порядке неубывания, и mm запросов: найти первое и последнее вхождение числа в массив.

Входные данные:

В первой строке содержится одно число n – размер массива (1≤n≤100000).

Во второй строке находится n чисел в порядке неубывания – элементы массива.

В третьей строке находится число m – количество запросов.

В последней строке находится m чисел – запросы.

Выходные данные:

Для каждого запроса выведите в отдельной строке номер первого и последнего вхождения этого числа в массив. Если числа в массиве нет, выведите -1 -1.

STDIN:

5

1 1 2 2 2

3

1 2 3

STDOUT:

1 2

3 5

-1 -1

Я не совсем понимаю как проверять эти запросы.

Comment: Вы не хотите воспользоваться, раз уж С++, [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range)?

Comment: @Harry да я боюсь подобные команды использовать, в ВУЗе требуют всё своими ручками реализовывать, порой до абсурда доходит

Comment: @Hobble, ответы на   подобные вопросы  вы можете получать быстрей, просто посмотрев как реализовано в стандартной библиотеке

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то предлагаю следующий алгоритм: первым шагом бинарным поиском находим искомый элемент. Если его нет, отваливаемся. Если есть, вторым шагом бинарным поиском в левой половине находим элемент, слева от которого элемент меньше него. Он гарантировано есть если нашелся элемент на первом шаге. Справа аналогично.

Comment: Вы приняли ответ, который рассматривает ваш код, и при этом стираете свой код, делая ответ абстрактным. Это здесь называется вандализацией вопроса. Имейте уважению к человеку, который потратил время на разбор вашего кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша функция бинарного немного неправильна...

1. По условию задачи вам нужно искать диапазон вхождения числа в массив. А вы возвращаете один индекс. Возвращайте пару или объект своей структуры с 2-мя значениями. Также, возвращать `false` нельзя, т.к. `false == 0`, а `0` - легитимный индекс ответа, т.е. искомое число может находиться по индексу 0.
2. Параметр `middle` вообще не используется внутри функции, зачем было его передавать? Вы взяли определение от рекурсивной функции, а реализацию сделали циклическую. Также для вашей задачи не нужно начало и конец массива, нужно только количество элементов (размер массива). А т.к. у вас `c++` и можно воспользоваться `vector<int>` для хранения, то и размер можно не передавать.

```
// вместо 
int BinSearch (int numb_to_find, int m[], int start, int end, int middle) {}
// получится
pair<int, int> BinSearch (int numb_to_find, vector<int>&m) {}
```

3. В функцию вы передаете первое и последнее число, содержащееся в массиве. А надо вообще-то передавать индексы. А так у вас будет неопределенное поведение, связанное с выходом за границы массива. А в массиве могут быть и отрицательные числа!

```
int result = BinSearch(find, m, m[0], m[n-1], 0); // в качестве индексов передаются числа
int BinSearch () {
    while (start <= end) {
        if (m[middle] == numb_to_find) {} // которые используются как индексы
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно самостоятельно реализовать бинарный поиск, то нужно воспользоваться его модификациями, дающими результат, похожий на lower_bound и upper_bound - первое и последнее вхождение элемента, либо индекс, куда его можно было бы вставить, если элемент отсутствует

```
int BinSearchLeft (int numb_to_find, int m[], int start, int end, int middle) {
   end++;
   while (start < end) {
      middle = (start + end) / 2;
      if (m[middle] < numb_to_find) 
          start = middle + 1;
      else
          end = middle;
   return start;
 }

int BinSearchRight (int numb_to_find, int m[], int start, int end, int middle) {
   end++;
   while (start < end) {
      middle = (start + end) / 2;
      if (m[middle] <= numb_to_find) 
          start = middle + 1;
      else
          end = middle;
   return end - 1;
 }
```